# TypeScript private property with leading underscore not being checked by IDE

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

When I name my private property with leading underscore, it is not marked as unused. If I remove the underscore it works as expected and the property grays out. How can I set unused property checking also for underscore variables?

Correct behavior, variable grayed out when unused:

[image: Correct behavior]

Wrong behavior, variable with leading underscore not grayed out when unused:

[image: Wrong behavior]

I use WebStorm 2019.3.5 with Angular 9.1.3

Comment: Prefixing unused parameters with an underscore (`_`) makes them exempt from the unused parameter check if `tsc` is invoked with certain flags (see [here][1]). I suspect this is the cause. I wish I could help more, but I am not a WebStorm user myself.
 
  [1]: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#flag-unused-declarations-with---nounusedparameters-and---nounusedlocals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional (done at [users' request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38437)): there is a common convention (used by tsc and modern linters) to mark variables, parameters, etc. that shouldn't be reported as unused by prefixing them with underscore

Comment: There is no option for TypeScript config or WebStorm settings to change this behavior?

Comment: No option, sorry:(